# MC Journey RowCount and lookup function help, please

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

my Marketing Cloud (MC) Journey Data Extension(DE) is set to SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP ==CampaignMember:Common:Id. this DE can have the duplicate CampaignMember:Common:Id with a unique CampaignMember:Id.

At the time of the record injections. The column "CampaignMember:Attendee_Status__c" is == to Registered. Once the record is injected, any records updated will be ignored by the journey. However, I have a daily import of the updated attendance record into another DE. whose SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP == "Member ID". FYI, another column in this DE is "Lead_Contact ID" and those records also match with the Journeys DE column CampaignMember:Common:Id.

This issue is. If the attendance status record is Canceled I need to exclude the email.

so this works if the DE SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP == CampaignMember:Id `RowCount(LookupRows("TEST CT Attendance Status","Attendee Status","Canceled","Member ID",_subscriberkey))>0`

but doesn't work if the SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP ==CampaignMember:Common:Id

and because I cannot change the productions journey DE from CampaignMember:Common:Id to CampaignMember:Id. I don't know how to tweak the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not change subscriber relationship as you describe. See further below for details.

You should instead change your exclusion lookup to use the campaignMember:id instead of _subscriberKey for matching with attendance status DE:

```
RowCount(LookupRows("TEST CT Attendance Status","Attendee Status","Canceled","Member ID","CampaignMember:Id"))>0
```

**Edit**: Or so I thought. While this is logically correct, this won't work as you apparently cannot use entry source data (= in our case, the field reference "CampaignMember:Id") for exclusion script. Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320456&type=1

From your edit I saw that your "Lead_Contact ID" is also in the exclusion DE, which matches _subscriberKey.

So in order to stay in the "lookups by personalization string" limits you have to use that one to lookup:

```
RowCount(LookupRows("TEST CT Attendance Status_cancelled","Attendee Status","Canceled","Lead_Contact ID",_subscriberKey))>0
```

Now if this is logically sound depends on whether your Data Extension holds members to many campaigns. If all are from the same campaign, it's fine as Lead ID and Member ID will be in a 1:1 relationship.

If your DE holds members from more than one campaign, then you'll have to extend the lookup to include your relevant campaign ID, as one lead could be in that DE with different campaign member IDs and statuses.

That would then look like this (if your campaignId is in the field of the name "campaignID" and assuming that we can work with a static one in the usecase):

```
RowCount(LookupRows("TEST CT Attendance Status_cancelled","Attendee Status","Canceled","Lead_Contact ID",_subscriberKey,"campaignId","701xxxxxxxxxx"))>0
```

**end edit**

===

Other than that:

- About the concept of subscriber relationship:

Subscriber Relationship tells the SFMC system which field defines the "Person" in the DE that you want to send to. That sendout will try to find existing contacts based on this ID and if it finds none, create a billable contact off of that field's value. Best case: One Person - one billable contact.

So: Subscriber Relationship should be put only on the DE field that contains IDs used for "persons".

Your field:
CampaignMember:Common:Id refers to either a Lead (`00Q` Ids) or Contact (`003` Ids) >>  These IDs are used to represent "Persons" >> good.
So: keep using that in your subscriber relationship.

You should *not* change the subscriber relationship to something like a campaign member Id. One "person" can have many campaign member IDs (because they can be in multiple campaigns as members). Setting subscriber relationship to this will create billable contacts out of your campaign members (`00v` type IDs) upon sending. In other words, you'll make the system bill you more than once, for the same person.

- Reference for all the IDs described:
  https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-object-key-prefix-list/

If this sounds like gibberish:

- Familiarize yourself with how Leads / Contacts, Campaigns and CampaignMembers work in Salesforce.
- Familiarize yourself with the concept of "contact count" in SFMC

Comment: Thank you, Jonas for that clear explanation, very much appreciated. I tried the syntax you suggested and I'm getting a validation error on the excusion.

Comment: just forgot to include the double-quotes. got it to run. I've tested the syntax, you provided. it ignores the exclusion. all 4 persons received the email including the two whose Attendance == Canceled. Any suggestion, Please?

Comment: Debug / isolate; Hard to do this without actually seeing your data. Visually output %%CampaignMember:Id%% somewhere in the email and check the preview for a relevant user. You should be seeing their campaign member ID, some `00v` id. Verify that this exact ID actually is in your exclusion DE with a "canceled" status.

Comment: Example Canceled record: Exclusion DE "member ID"=00v4P00002K5pyFQAR and "Lead_Contact ID"== 00Q4P000015Ah6aUAC // JB DE "CampaignMember:Id"== 00v4P00002K5pyFQAR and "CampaignMember:Common:Id"== 00Q4P000015Ah6aUAC. I added the variables into the email and did a preview test will no errors and it showed the correct ID's in the email %%CampaignMember:Id%%
%%CampaignMember:Common:Id%%

Comment: ok then it "should" work, but I think I found out why it doesnt. updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonas, adding the CampaignID and a hardcoded 704xxx id worked. The exclusion DE holds members from more than one campaign and the JB DE is connected to one campaign. So I added a new field on the Exclusion DE called campaignId with the default value == to the hardcoded 704xxx ID. then on the JB email, I  updated the email exclusions with your 2nd provided sample that includes the same hardcoded 704xx ID.